# Issue in understanding java method

Tags: java

maybe I've a serious gap in java fondamental comprehension. In the code below I can't understand how getLength method can calculate walk length. Why recall itself on tail?

```
class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        // Walk w1 = new Right(new Down(new Left(new Up(new Stop()))));
        Move w2 = new Left(new Left(new Up(new Stop())));
        // Walk w3=new Right(new Stop());
        System.out.println(w2.tail);
    }
}

abstract class Walk {

    public abstract boolean isStop();

    public abstract int getLength();
}

class Stop extends Walk {

    @Override
    public boolean isStop() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return 0;
    }
}

abstract class Move extends Walk {

    Walk tail;


    @Override
    public int getLength() {

        return 1 + tail.getLength();
    }

    Move(Walk tail) {
        this.tail = tail;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStop() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Right extends Move {

    public Right(Walk tail) {

        super(tail);

    }
}

class Left extends Move {

    public Left(Walk tail) {
        super(tail);
    }
}

class Up extends Move {

    public Up(Walk tail) {
        super(tail);
    }
}

class Down extends Move {

    public Down(Walk tail) {
        super(tail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be creating your own linked list, and the `getLength()` method iterates through the entire list, returning the full sum.

As an aside, please work on your code formatting for this site, especially your indentation.

Comment: So exist only one instance of Move?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione: no, many instances of Move exist, and they are attached to each other in a linked-list.

Comment: In which variable they are attached and how variable tail can contain this chain?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione: please look at your own code. See which variable refers to the classes you're posting here.

Comment: Ah ok, tail in move W2 contain the chain?

Answer (score 0):

It calculates the total length, from what I can tell.

```
return 1+tail.getLength();
```

This appears to say that the current object's walk length is `1`, and it adds that to whatever `tail` walk length is. This gives the total length.

***NOTE***: Whoever wrote this, should look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).